# How to use bit-fields in order to copy data into a struct from a binary?

Tags: c++, binary, bit-fields

I have a binary file that I am trying to extract data from. The last 5 data points int the file are 10 bit integer types and I am struggling on how to extract that information and convert it into something readable. I have tried the following code:

```
struct bitField
{
    unsigned value: 10;
};

struct Data
{
    bitField x;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<char,696> buffer;
    std::ifstream file ("file.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    file.read(buffer.data(),buffer.size());

    Data a;

    std::memcpy(&a.x.value,&buffer[612],sizeof(struct bitField));

}
```

I am then met with the error `attempt to take address of bit-field`. I have then tried using `std::bitset<10>` in place of bitField in my Data struct. And while I do not get a compiler error, I get back a bunch of 0's instead which I believe is incorrect data.

How do you properly read in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take an address of a bit-field value as it may not be byte-aligned.  You should copy directly into a.x (not a.x.value).

Further, you don't really need to have a separate bitfield struct.  You can simply put bitfields right into Data struct.

See this on how to use bitfields:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bit-fields-c/

Comment: I would suggest to use a c++ reference (eg [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)) instead of a c one (not that it matters much in this case)